# Successful Request despite missing 'Bearer'

Tags: security, http-headers, office365, bearer-token, microsoft-graph-api

Ok,

So i have a request to the Microsoft Graph API which is used to create a folder on One Drive. Generally all of my requests have the header:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"
```

Specifying that i am requesting access using a token of type Bearer.

However, one request seems to have slipped through the net.

This request has the following structure:

```
{
    Method: POST,
    RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/<tenantid>/groups/<groupid>/drive/items/<folderid>/children/',
    Version: 1.1,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent,
    Headers: {
        Authorization: <token>
        Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    }
}
```

As you can see the 'Bearer' keyword within the Authorization header is missing.

The strange thing is that this request was successful and the graph didnt need the keyword.

My question essentially is this:

Why was that request successful and are there any security considerations or oversights highlighted by this being successful?

Thanks,

Comment: Interesting find. It could simply be that `Bearer` is assumed to be the default  token type on the API side.

Comment: That was my assumption also. However, if this is assumed then i am slightly concerned as to what else may be 'assumed' and if there are any security implications to this. Well done Microsoft :)

Comment: I don't like edge cases like this in APIs, I prefer them to follow the spec to a T.

Comment: Precisely. What is the point in producing documentation if they themselves are not following it

Comment: I personally agree that it maybe the default token type , specify another token type, like ‘MAC’ , It will get the “401 Unauthorized” error .

Comment: Where is the request sent from - is it server-side or client-side?

Comment: Sent from Server Side to the Graph API

Comment: Does it work without the Bearer for other OneDrive API calls?

Comment: I havent tested it with other calls as i make it standard practice to include bearer and i am not sure how this one slipped through the net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback, folks! Please note that Microsoft Graph *beta* and *v1.0* API versions default to Bearer token type if the type is not provided. There is no security risk with this approach because it is the only supported token type as of April '16. Our documentation states that it the best practice to provide token type explicitly.

Please do note that while the RFC mandates that servers MUST support bearer but does not say anything about accepting tokens without it.

We will consider addressing this in the next API version.